# how to remove the decimal point

Tags: python, numpy

I use `numpy.loadtxt()` to read some numbers (integers) from files, however, when I print it, it displayed by scientific notation. I use suppress=True, in the end , the decimal disappear. But there is still a decimal point. How to remove?

[image]

Comment: Include some relevant code to demonstrate what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an optional argument of [`numpy.loadtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) called `dtype` which allows you to specify the datatype of the array. If you don't provide any argument, the default is float, which is what you are seeing.

Therefore, you can do something like:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("filename.txt", dtype=np.int16)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I have another question: data is a array , I use it multiply a matrix, it' ok ? I don't know why them can multiply?

Comment: @liangpu597  I would use pandas if data size is very big, I experienced performance issues with with `np.loadtxt`. check also this http://akuederle.com/stop-using-numpy-loadtxt. `pandas.read_csv('filename.txt', sep=' ', header=None, dtype=int).values`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your numpy type to `int` before printing.

```
# Create example data
example = np.random.rand(10, 2)*10

# Print as integer
print(example.astype(int))
```